# Cannot find module with Webpack, Typescript, custom module directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, webpack

## What I'm trying to do

I am wrote a dummy module **my-component** which essentially exports a single class **Something**. I placed it in **app/modules/**. Now I am tying to access it using the import Syntax from **app/app.js**:

```
import { Something } from 'my-component';
```

**Expectation**: With my current Webpack configuration (below) I would expect this to work.

**Actual**: This throws the error:

```
ERROR in [default] /<project_dir>/app/app.ts:1:26
Cannot find module 'my-component/Something'.
```

## What I tried to fix it

I know the module in itself is defined correctly, because

1. I can import it using a relative path: `import { Something } from './my-component'`
2. I can import it as-is, if I move the module to `node_modules/my-component`.

The only combination that fails is importing it without a relative path from my **modules/** directory. So I think the issue might be my Webpack configuration.

## Setup Details

As you can see below, I have two directories listed as **resolve.root**:

- `project_dir/app`
- `project_dir/node_modules`

It seems to manage to resolve from `node_modules`, just not from `app`.

**Project layout**

```
                               Webpack
project_dir/
 ├── app/                      context, resolve.root
 │    ├── app.ts
 │    └── my-component/
 │         ├── index.ts
 │         └── Something.ts
 ├── webpack.config.js
 ├── node_modules/             resolve.root
 │    ├── ...
 │    ├── ...
 │    └── ...
 └── dist/
      └── ...
```

**app/app.ts**

```
import { Something } from 'my-component/Something';
```

**app/my-component/index.ts**

```
export { Something } from './Something'
```

**app/my-component/Something.ts**

```
class Something {
}

export { Something };
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path'),
  ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '.');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(ROOT, 'app'),
  entry: 'app.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(ROOT, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: [
      '', '.ts', '.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

**EDIT**
Fixed the project layout.

Comment: Not confident that this is relevant, so just a comment:  Have you tried `import { Something } from './my-component/Something';` in app.ts?  Relative paths must start with ./, etc.  If it doesn't, then "node_modules" is assumed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Cannot find module**

If you experience this issue with **dynamic module loading** using `ESNEXT`,

you have to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 6):

I found an easier solution than the previously accepted one:

**In your typescript configuration, set the `baseUrl` in the `compilerOptions`**:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

Webpack and Typescript use node module resolution by default, which is fine.
When setting up custom module folders though, you need to configure them in both the Webpack and the Typescript config.
Changes to the Webpack module resolution config are not propagated to the Typescript compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I created a replica of your project structure. It seems that the case is that the *import* statement does not behave the same as the *require*, AND, webpack resolve.root config works as expected with it.

For the modules, change your *import* statements to *require* like this:

**app.ts**

```
// Define require function for TypeScript to know that it
// will exist at runtime
declare function require(name:string);
// Require your module
var Something = require('my-component/Something');
// var myComponent = require('my-component');
```

**my-component/Something.ts**

```
// Export something (used a function to test)
export function Something() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

**my-component/index.ts**

```
// Definition of require function as mentioned before
declare function require(name:string);
// Passing other modules
var exportedModules = {
    Something: require("my-component/Something")
};
export default exportedModules;
```

Like this, it will work without problems and resolve with the module names as you defined in Webpack. Unfortunately, I couldn't achieve it with the *import*.

I pushed the solution to a [repository](https://github.com/NeaSTDL/webpack-typescript-require). Check it out if you need!

Comment: I specifically don't want to reference it relatively, because components might be outsourced to separate projects and installed via npm. If relative paths are used, these references will break.

My understanding of resolve.root is that this is what it's supposed to do: https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html ("...directories in the configuration option resolve.root are prepended...")

Comment: Got the point! I'll edit the answer with the corresponding approach.

Comment: Sorry this was my bad -- I listed the project config wrong. The webpack.config.js is at root level of the project. Sorry about that.

Comment: Changed answer to present new solution. Please, check and comment.

Comment: You're right, the only way I see it working is with the require syntax. The issue seems to be that the imports don't get resolved properly yet with the "import ... from absolutePath" syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I found a different solution via configuration.

Comment: @JeffreyHammansson What was the configuration based method? I can't see it here. Perhaps just missing it?